# how to find result with any word in list in django

Tags: python, django

I would like to find a list of results that are contained that match any word in a list.

For example if company have different inputs it could still find them:

```
company_name = 'awesome blossom'
```

I would like to search for companies with 'awesome' and 'blossom' in the name.

I tried something like this:

```
companies = Company.objects.filter(company_name__icontains__in=company_name.split(' ')
```

but this didn't work.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably such statement will work:

```
Company.objects.filter(reduce(and_, [Q(company_name__icontains=s) for s in company_name.split(' ')]))
```

Comment: `reduce` is not in the default namespace in Python 3.

Comment: from functools import reduce?

Answer (score 2):

You should you `Q` objects in django.

```
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Company

query = Company.objects.filter(
    Q(company_name__icontains='awesome') & 
    Q(company_name__icontains='blossom')
)
```

Reference: https://micropyramid.com/blog/django-database-access-optimization/

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to search for companies with 'awesome' **and** 'blossom' in the name.

You will need to construct a query with one condition for each element in your list. As you state in the quote, these conditions must be *ANDed*.

You can do this by appending multiple filters, like this:

```
companies = Company.objects.all()
for word in company_name.split():
    companies = companies.filter(company_name__icontains=word)
```

As Django is smart enough, this should result in a single query to the database.

Another more fancy way to do this is using `Q` object and the `reduce` function.

```
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce

Company.objects.filter(reduce(Q.__and__, [Q(company_name__icontains=word) for word in company_name.split()]))
```

For this example both queries should be equivalent.

Comment: It would be a lot more clear to the OP if you do not `reduce`  the `Q objects`. This also does not help if there is a situation like `condition 1` *AND* `condition 2` *OR* `condition 3`. So, writing them out explicitly and connecting them using logical operators would make a lot more sense.

Comment: The words "awesome" and  "blossom" are just an example. Probably these words come from an user input, in which case the amount of words may vary, hence we must do it in a dynamic way.